# Rendering Issues in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am having issues rendering the apostrophe in my code:

```
if (type == 'Survivor') {
display = isProxy ? (finishedRegistration ? '' : 'Unfinished ') + (name.substr(name.length - 1) == 's' ? name + '&rsquo;' : name + '&rsquo;s') + ' Survivor Profile' : 'My ' + (finishedRegistration ? '' : 'Unfinished ') + (locationName ? (locationId == NineElevenRegistries.constants.lookups.survivorLocationWtc911ElsewhereId ? '9/11' : locationName) : '') + ' Survivor Profile';}
```

The apostrophe character is rendered as `&rsquo`, in profile link (should be `Rafal M 
Proxy 1's Survivor Profile` and is `Rafal M Proxy 1&rsquos Survivor Profile`).

Display:

```
Name:NineElevenRegistries.helpers.profile.getDisplayName(profile.IsProxyProfile(‌​), true, profile.Name().trim(), 'Survivor', profile.Location() ? profile.Location().Id : '', profile.Location() ? profile.Location().Name : '')
```

Comment: Wow, that code is horrible to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `&rsquo;` : simply write a ' character.
From javascript you may either escape it like `'\''` or enclose it in double quotes like `"'"`.